# UITextField Inputformatting

Tags: ios, time, uitextfield

I am coding a little app, that will help me in my daily work. Therefore the App should calculate timevalues.
I have got a uitextfield at the top of the app.

Now I want to format the user's input while typing. 
After every 2 digits I want to insert a :

Like the fantastic app "Timecode" does.

Can you give me a hint, how to realize my wish, please?

[image: Screenshot "Timecode" App]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` delegate method of `UITextField`

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
     NSString *tempString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
     NSArray *temp  = [tempString componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
     NSString *test = [temp lastObject];
     if([test length] == 2)
     {
          test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",test];
          tempString = @"";
          for(int loop = 0;loop<[temp count]-1;loop++)
          {
              tempString = [tempString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@:",[temp objectAtIndex:loop]];
          }
          if([temp count] != 1)
              tempString = [tempString stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@",test];
          else
              tempString = test;
      }
    textField.text = tempString;
    return NO;
}
```

The above code will work in normal case. If user edited in between the characters it will have issues, you need to manage that also.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have solved it with your tipps. Thanks again

Comment: @Raphael: With pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

This code will work for you....

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSCharacterSet *numberSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789"];
    if(string.length == 0)
    {
        return YES;
    }
    else if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:numberSet].location == NSNotFound)
    {
        return NO;
    }

    NSString *textFieldText = [textField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@":" withString:@""];

    if((string.length == 1) && (textFieldText.length > 0) && (textFieldText.length % 2) == 0)
        textField.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@:",textField.text];

    return YES;

}
```

I checked and working fine for your requirement.